# upload image via a jquery ui modal form

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, uploader

i am trying to upload an image through a jquery ui modal form..

is it possible? i am having problem on how to get the value from the modal..

i have been searching through the net but there is no clear answer..

do anyone have any idea about it?

this is my javascript code for the modal form:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 400,
                position: "center",
                buttons: {
                    "Upload": function() {


                                                           var pos= $("#pos input:radio:checked").val();
                                                           // i still don't know how to get the value for the image uploaded

                                                           $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                                            },
                    "Cancel": function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
                                     }
            });
               });
```

this is my modal form:

```
<div id='dialog' title='ADD IMAGE' class='ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content'>
        <form id='myform' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <fieldset>
        <div id='pos'>
        <p class='applyimage'>Where do you want to apply a background image?</p>
        <p class='applyimage'><input type='radio' class='position' name='position' id='header' value='header' checked='checked'/>&nbsp;<label for='header'>Header</label>
        <input type='radio' class='position' name='position' id='body' value='body'/>&nbsp;<label for='body'>Body</label>
        <input type='radio' class='position' name='position' id='footer' value='footer'/>&nbsp;<label for='footer'>Footer</label></p>
        <p class='applyimage'><input type='file' name='data[Image][fileName]' id='imgup'/></p>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you don't use the "buttons" parameter,
instead create the Upload button on your form.

If you do nothing else, it will load the action your form was set to.

---

If you really want to use the "buttons" parameter (to keep the style the same), you shouldn't have a problem forcing the submission of the form with javascript function() { $("#formName").submit(); }

I'd suggest doing an ajax call to do the submission though and catch it with the .success or .error handler to take the next step.

You'll have to work a lot with updating the modal div you created.  And only close it after .success.